# FB Auto Group Poster with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

Currently I am trying to build a FB bot that can post a string of text and a video url to Facebook groups that I am a part of. I am helping a family member with this so that their workflow can be automated.

My problem is: I got the code using selenium to login and go to the groups that I am a part of, however it cannot find the element on the page for the post box where I need to pass in my string of text and video url. I tried by copying the full xpath but it cannot find that element. Please let me know if there are any ideas, this has been driving me crazy!

Here is the error I am getting: The error I am getting is from this line of code (line 51):

post_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div")

Error message: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

How could it not locate the element if I passed in the full xpath?

Here is my code:

---

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def main():

    # Your Facebook account user and password
    usr = "****"
    pwd = "****"
    message = "Checkout an amazing selenium script for posting in Facebook Groups!\nhttps://github.com/lalongooo/selenium-fb-group-poster"
    attach_video = True
    video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70UXjyy6K84"
    

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2 # 1:allow, 2:block 
    })

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(15) # seconds

    # Go to facebook.com
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
    
    # Enter user email
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
    elem.send_keys(usr)
    # Enter user password
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
    elem.send_keys(pwd)
    # Login
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    groups = ['3069593553138733', '345263603157484']
    
    time.sleep(5)
    
    for i in range(len(groups)):
    
        # Navigate to group url
    
        driver.get('https://facebook.com/groups/'+groups[i])

        # Click on the write something box
        post_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div")
        post_box.click()
        

        # Enter the text we want to post to Facebook
        post_box.send_keys(message)


        post_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button/span")
        clickable = False
        while not clickable:
            cursor = post_button.find_element_by_tag_name('span').value_of_css_property("cursor")
            if cursor == "pointer":
                clickable = True
                break
        post_button.click()
        sleep(5)

    # driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

---

Comment: Did you check if the element could be inside a frame tag?

Comment: Need HTML code.

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_TOS 3.2_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use [_Facebook Graph API_](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) instead.

Comment: _“I am helping a family member with this so that their workflow can be automated.”_ - sounds like you are trying to enable a spammer, tbh.